# urllib2 get response through error

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to log onto a website that throws me a "401: Authentication Required" error and then crashes. The script crashes on the `urllib2.open(url)` so I cannot currently read the response.  How can I get the data from this response other than the error?

Comment: do you mean raises an error by crashing?

Comment: Why do you think they'll be data if you're not authenticated to view it? Or, is your real question "How do I authenticate using urllib2 to view a webpage" ?

Comment: well , if you mean you don't want it crashing you could use try and except ..

Comment: @JonClements I am usiung Simplified Sign On to access this resource.  I am correctly authenticated into SSO. This resource seems to have extra layers of protection over it though.  The only piece of Data I am actually looking for is a redirect URL to a login, which the majority of 401 errors come with.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html

```
    >>> req = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
    >>> try:
    >>>     urllib2.urlopen(req)
    >>> except HTTPError, e:
    >>>     print e.code
    >>>     print e.read()
    >>>
    404
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <?xml-stylesheet href="./css/ht2html.css" type="text/css"?>
    ...... etc...
```